# In iOS how to get the keyWindow when use UIStoryboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

The following piece of code doesn't work for me:

```
UIWindow * win = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"keyButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 50, 50)];

[win addSubview:button];
```

In my project, when I use the storyboard, the code doesn't work. However without using storyboard it works normally. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Be specific. What result do you get when you run this code? Is win nil? Where do you have this code? Why are you trying to add a button directly to your window in the first place (rather than a view of a view controller)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using storyboard, you should not call this snippet in viewDidLoad, call this in viewDidAppear or after the view has been appeared.